# Client java udp won't send to C# server

Tags: java, c#, swing, networking, udp

UPDATE: I fixed the null pointer issue, and it appears to be sending from the java program. However it does not seem to be recieving properly. as a matter of fact, the recieve thread funciton is being called only once.

I add this code to the initModel method in the C# code:

```
    ThreadStart threadFunction = new ThreadStart(ReceiveThreadFunction);
    _receiveDataThread = new Thread(threadFunction);
    _receiveDataThread.Start();
```

---

I am trying to send a string upon button click from the java program. However I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pkgfinal.Client$1.actionPerformed(Client.java:90)
```

This error occurs on this line of code:

```
          socket.send(sendPacket);
```

JAVA CODE:

```
public class Client extends JFrame 
{

      // set up GUI and DatagramSocket
   public Client()
   {
      super( "Client" );
      //enterField = new JTextField( "Type message here" );
      InitGUI();

   }

       //GUI initializer
    public void InitGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,400);

        //Create Panels
        display = new JPanel();


        //Create TextFields
        enterField = new JTextField( "Type message here" ); 
        //Create TextFields
        enterField = new JTextField(12);
        enterField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24)); 
        enterField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);


        messageSend = enterField.getText();


        //Create button
        displayButton = new JButton("Display");


        displayButton.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() 
         { 
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
            {
               try // create and send packet
               {
                 //***********************************************
                 //Enter code to get text from the field and send as socket
                 //**********************************************
                  //String message = event.getActionCommand();
                  displayArea.append("\nSending packet containing: "+ messageSend+"\n");

                  byte[] data = messageSend.getBytes();

                  DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 1234);
                  socket.send(sendPacket);

                  displayArea.append( "Packet sent\n" );
                  displayArea.setCaretPosition( displayArea.getText().length() );

               } // end try
               catch ( IOException ioException ) 
               {
                  displayArea.append( ioException + "\n" );
                  ioException.printStackTrace();
               } // end catch

            } // end actionPerformed
         } // end inner class
      ); // end call to addActionListener 

     try // create DatagramSocket for sending and receiving packets
  {
     socket = new DatagramSocket();
  } // end try
  catch ( SocketException socketException ) 
  {
     socketException.printStackTrace();
     System.exit( 1 );
  } // end catch
```

C# Server Code MainWindowXaml.cs:

```
    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // create an instance of our Model
       model = new Model();
       DataContext = model;

        //this.GameGrid.DataContext = model;

        SevenSegmentLED.ItemsSource = model.tileCollection;
        //SET THE LOCAL PORT AND IP
        model.SetLocalNetworkSettings(1234, "127.0.0.1");




    }
```

Inside my Model.cs

```
        //Some data that keeps track of ports and addresses
        private static UInt32 _localPort;
        private static String _localIPAddress;

        public void SetLocalNetworkSettings(UInt32 port, String ipAddress)
        {
            _localPort = port;
            _localIPAddress = ipAddress;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("CALLED");

        }

  public void initModel()
        {


            try
            {
                // ***********************************************
                // set up generic UDP socket and bind to local port
                // ***********************************************
                _dataSocket = new UdpClient((int)_localPort);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Write(ex.ToString());

            }
        ThreadStart threadFunction = new ThreadStart(ReceiveThreadFunction);
        _receiveDataThread = new Thread(threadFunction);
        _receiveDataThread.Start();

        }



  // this is the thread that waits for incoming messages
        private void ReceiveThreadFunction()
        {
            //Setup Receive end point
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // wait for data
                    Byte[] receiveData = _dataSocket.Receive(ref endPoint);

                    // check to see if this is synchronization data 
                    // ignore it. we should not recieve any sychronization
                    // data here, because synchronization data should have 
                    // been consumed by the SynchWithOtherPlayer thread. but, 
                    // it is possible to get 1 last synchronization byte, which we
                    // want to ignore
                    if (receiveData.Length < 2)
                    {
                        continue;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("RECIEVED SOMETHING");


                    }



                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                    String data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveData);

                    char[] ary = data.ToCharArray();




                    // update status window
                    //StatusTextBox = StatusTextBox + DateTime.Now + ":" + " New message received.\n";

                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    // got here because either the Receive failed, or more
                    // or more likely the socket was destroyed by 
                    // exiting from the JoystickPositionWindow form
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }

            }
        }
```

Comment: The NPE occurs because `socket` hasn't been initialised (at least in the code shown). So it's `null`, and you're asking it to send a packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so we're getting a `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
socket.send(sendPacket);
```

We initialize `sendPacket` the line before, so it's definitely not that. So then `socket` must be null.

You never initialized `socket`! So it's null, causing your exception. You have to create an instance of a `Socket`.

The code for that might look something like:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested, and it appears to be sending, but it does not appear to be recieving from my C# program

Comment: In this line: `_dataSocket = new UdpClient((int)_localPort)`, `_localPort` is 1234, right?

I have done much networking in C#, I'm not familiar with the libraries.

Comment: yes, _localPort is 1234, it is set from here model.SetLocalNetworkSettings(1234, "127.0.0.1");

Comment: Hmm I don't actually know, sorry. It all looks fine to me. Either I'm missing something in the code in your question or there's something else in the rest of your code causing issues...?

You are running these on the same machine, right?

Comment: They are running on the same machine

Comment: I don't know then, sorry :P. Good luck though :)